# URL Trailing Slashes Effecting The HTACCESS Redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have successfully redirect my sites URL from **"localhost/example/user.php?u=user1"** to **"localhost/example/user1"** with the following Htaccess code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ user.php?u=$1
```

But now when I open my site with a trailing slash **"localhost/example/user1/"** it redirects me to **localhost/user1**, I have tried many ways to eliminate that trailing slash from url but its not working.

How it can be done?

THANKS.

Comment: You have other mod rewrite rules somewhere?

Comment: @JonLin, no sir, this is the full coding of my .htaccess file,
`#1 1--- Establish a custom 404 page.
ErrorDocument 404 /filenotfound.php
#2 2----- Prevent directory file
IndexIgnore *
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ user.php?u=$1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the RewriteBase to your working dir.

```
RewriteBase /example/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ user.php?u=$1
```

Comment: RewriteBase is not working its giving this error: **Not Found

The requested URL /var/www/web_intersect/user.php was not found on this server.**

Comment: After trying alot I have set RewriteBase to **RewriteBase /web_intersect/** and when I try to open site with a slash at the end **localhost/example/user1/** it open but without CSS styles.

Comment: Sorry my fault. I edited the code above. How to you include your CSS styles? You should provide the path absolute. So if you include them like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />` you have to provide the absolute path like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/class.css" />`. Alternatively you can set the base url like this `<base href="http://localhost/example" />`.

Comment: I was including stylesheet like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />`, I updated them to `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="localhost/css/style.css" />` and it worked. Thanks.